# How do I update the same model using different controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got one big model, with a large number of fields. I'd like to split them up into two separate pages, and have them editable separately. I'd preferably like to handle Part A and Part B in two different controllers.

As it stands, Page B uses the 'New' and 'Edit' methods in the controller, but still posts to the controller for Page A. I can't seem to force it to use the controller for Page B. Thus, when validation fails for fields on Page B, I'm redirected to Page A.

It's kind of a weird question, but if anyone has some advice, it'd be much appreciated.

EDIT:

In controller A(associated with the model):

```
@modA = ModelA.new(params[:model_a])
@modA.id = current_user.id

respond_to do |format|
  if @modA.save            
    format.html {redirect_to('/model_a/new', :notice => "ModelA successfully created.") }
  else
    format.html {render action: 'new'}
  end
end
```

That's basically all that's needed - if I could redirect, conditionally, to the other controllers 'edit' or 'create' actions, i'd be all set.

Comment: Please post your routes and controller code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that in your views for Page B's new and edit pages, you're doing something like `form_for(@modA)`. This automatically uses the routes that go with that model. You can confirm this by looking at the action attribute of the form in the source of your pages in the browser.

Instead, you can specify which controller and route you want to use:

```
form_for(@modA, url: {controller: 'page_b', action: 'create'}) do
  ...
```

Please post your views if my guess isn't what you have or if this suggestion doesn't help.